# MSFT Azure Function App not sending emails via Graph API (works on desktop)

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to send emails from a Function App via MS Graph API using client credentials workflow and Application permissions.

Basically the app detects a file landing in a storage account, triggers the app and fires the email.

Works on my desktop in VS Code as expected. I am on a corporate network behind a proxy.

However, on testing in the FA in Azure, although we get a successful invocation, no email is sent - our EO mailbox logs show nothing received.

Here's the log from the FA Monitor.

```
    2022-06-09T02:40:44.016 [Information] Executing 'Functions.email-via-graph-api' (Reason='New blob detected: failed/2022-05-18_15h41m00s_0266201111_0266207713_2.pdf', Id=c11e670f-423a-4427-af8d-b11d61192bce)
2022-06-09T02:40:44.016 [Information] Trigger Details: MessageId: 235a0fba-0210-46b9-a82b-50a4a858a490, DequeueCount: 1, InsertionTime: 2022-06-09T02:40:43.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2022-06-07T03:15:04.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2022-06-09T02:40:35.000+00:00
2022-06-09T02:40:44.046 [Information] BEGIN: Sending email for failed referral via Graph API.
2022-06-09T02:40:44.046 [Information] Blob Name: 2022-05-18_15h41m00s_0266201111_0266207713_2.pdf
2022-06-09T02:40:44.046 [Information] Blob URI: https://STORAGEACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net/failed/2022-05-18_15h41m00s_0266201111_0266207713_2.pdf
2022-06-09T02:40:44.047 [Information] Executed 'Functions.email-via-graph-api' (Succeeded, Id=c11e670f-423a-4427-af8d-b11d61192bce, Duration=44ms)
```

If I look at Application Insights I can see the token call and Graph call.

Here's the setup:

- We have Application Permissions for mail.send against the AD App.
- We have 2 emails (a service/automation account and Exchange Online
  generic account) in a mail group allowed to access the AD App->Graph
  API FA
- Our FA is attached to a VNET, route-all set true
- All internal-destined traffic routes internally (and these are all internal alert emails)
- Our public/outbound traffic is VNET NAT'd to a /30 public prefix.
- Our NSG and proxy allow out SMTP (any to any) on ports 25 and 587 plus the IPV4 subnets from item 56 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide)

The call via axios is below. Again, works on the desktop

```
  try {
console.log(JSON.stringify(email, null, 2));
const response = await axios({
  url: `${GRAPH_ENDPOINT}/v1.0/users/${FROM_ADDRESS}/sendMail`,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  data: JSON.stringify(email),
});
```

Many thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

This is now working. However I don't have an explanation for why that it is. There seems to be some kind of delay between deployment of code and then it actually being the code base that's used by the FA.

I can actually replicate that in other calls in the code (to an API for example). When I run the code in VS Code I need to use a proxy when I make API calls to outside our organisation, and obviously if I deploy that code with proxy to FA, the FA won't work (as it is not going to use the proxy). If I remove the proxy and redeploy it takes about 5 mins for that change to take effect.

Utterly puzzling, though, why the Graph API call wasn't working at all for a day or so.